Unicode-Math: Bottom Accent horizontal positioning
Please consider this example:
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\Huge

\setmathfont{Latin Modern math}
\[\frac{\wideutilde{H}}{\widetilde{H}}\;
\frac{\mathunderbar{H}}{\wideoverbar{H}}\;
\frac{\underparen{H}}{\overparen{H}}\;
\frac{\underbrace{H}}{\overbrace{H}}\;
\text{\normalsize\bfseries Latin Modern}
\]

\setmathfont{New Computer Modern Math}
\[\frac{\wideutilde{H}}{\widetilde{H}}\;
\frac{\mathunderbar{H}}{\wideoverbar{H}}\;
\frac{\underparen{H}}{\overparen{H}}\;
\frac{\underbrace{H}}{\overbrace{H}}\;
\text{\normalsize\bfseries New Computer Modern}
\]

\setmathfont{TeXGyre Pagella Math}
\[\frac{\wideutilde{H}}{\widetilde{H}}\;
\frac{\mathunderbar{H}}{\wideoverbar{H}}\;
\frac{\underparen{H}}{\overparen{H}}\;
\frac{\underbrace{H}}{\overbrace{H}}\;
\text{\normalsize\bfseries TeXGyre Pagella}
\]

\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\[\frac{\wideutilde{H}}{\widetilde{H}}\;
\frac{\mathunderbar{H}}{\wideoverbar{H}}\;
\frac{\underparen{H}}{\overparen{H}}\;
\frac{\underbrace{H}}{\overbrace{H}}\;
\text{\normalsize\bfseries Cambria}
\]

\end{document}

and its output:

Unicode-Math places Top and bottom accents using the same "TopAccent" parameter which default value is to the glyph's center. This is fine for Upright letters but, IMHO, doesn’t work properly for Italics: top accents need to be shifted slightly to the right while bottom accents should be kept centered on the bottom of the glyph or possibly slightly shifted to the left.
A "BottomAccent" parameter independent of "TopAccent" would help here, its default value would be the center of the glyph’s bounding box.
Is there a better way to achieve correct horizontal positioning of both Top and Bottom accents for Upright and Italic letters?
Edit (2024/09/07): example reworked.

A possible (poor) hack consists in adding an invisible space to the accented glyph: this seems to prevent unicode-math to take the glyph's TopAccent value into account, thus aligning the bottom accent on the middle of the "composed" argument (space+glyph).
Here is the output of
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\[\frac{\wideutilde{\hspace{1sp}H}}{\widetilde{H}}\;
  \frac{\mathunderbar{\hspace{1sp}H}}{\wideoverbar{H}}\;
  \frac{\underparen{\hspace{1sp}H}}{\overparen{H}}\;
  \frac{\underbrace{\hspace{1sp}H}}{\overbrace{H}}\;
  \text{\normalsize\bfseries Latin Modern}
\]


Would it be possible to instruct unicode-math to forget considering TopAccent and systematically center bottom accents on the middle of the glyph? This would definitely be an improvement for italics and slanted glyphs as long as no BottomAccent is provided.
